# Ember-data: Best Json related resources

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, hateoas

Hi I am wondering which is the best solution to work with related resources in ember-data.
In order to build a REST backend.

1) embedded resources

```
user: {
id: "foo",
albums: [
 album: {
  id: "foo",
  name: "bar",
  description: "foobar",
 },
 album: {
  id: "foobar"
  name: "foobarfoo",
  description: "fumanchu",
 },
 ],
}
```

2) embedded id of the resources

```
user: {
 id: "foo",
 albums: [
   album: {
    id: "foo",
   },
   album: {
    id: "foobar"
   },
  ],
}
```

3) linked resources

```
user: {
 id: "blabla",
 links: {
   "self": { "href": "/users/blabla" },
   "albums": { "href": "/albums/blabla" }
 },
}
```

Do you think is possible to use hipermedia as in HATEOAS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "What is the best..." is not a really good way of asking this question. What constraints are you facing in building your app? Have you tried any of these methods and found drawbacks to them? What are you trying to accomplish? These will help knowledgeable people give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) gem?

It is the easier way to get the job done when working with Rails on the server side.

For relations, it may embed or use references to sub-resources. References (*which I would recommend*) are serialized this way:

```json
{
  users: [{
    id: 42,
    firstName: "John",
    albums: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  }]
}
```

```json
{
  albums: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Foo"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bar"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Buzz"
  }]
}
```

Here, albums may also be included as sideloaded data in the first hash:

```json
{
  users: [{
    id: 42,
    firstName: "John",
    albums: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  }],
  albums: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Foo"
  ...
  }]
}
```